# std::equal with reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, stl

Is it legal to use a `reverse_iterator` with `std::equal`?

For example, are any of these legal?

```
std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), w.rbegin())

std::equal(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), w.begin())

std::equal(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), w.rbegin())
```

Comment: All are, what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Xeo: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/ says under Parameters that it accepts forward iterators and has no mention of reverse iterators.

Comment: @trinithis : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator says that `std::reverse_iterator<>` inherits the iterator category of the underlying iterator, which for `std::vector<>` is random-access, which is a superset of forward.

Comment: You're mixing up iterator names and their categories. Also, [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) requires atleast input iterators, which are a subset of forward iterators.

Comment: reverse_iterators can be Forward Iterators, as confusing as that sounds.

Comment: @Benjamin : They _must_ be, actually, as the minimum iterator category requirement for `std::reverse_iterator<>` is bidirectional. ;-]

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was just going to type that up as an answer, but I guess that should be your privilege.

Comment: @wolfgang: I'm too lazy to formulate a complete answer right now, which is why I made a comment.  Go ahead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All are valid, because reverse iterators *are*, in fact, *forward iterators*.

"Reverse iterator" is not an iterator category.
Remember some iterator categories:

- An iterator that can be dereferenced (`*`) and incremented (`++`) is a forward iterator.
- A forward iterator that can also be decremented is a bidirectional iterator.
- A random access iterator is a biderectional iterator that also has `+` and `-` operators.

On the other hand, a reverse iterator is a bidirectional iterator or a random access iterator that looks at a collection in reverse. Look at

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/

... especially what it says about iterator_category under the "Member types" heading.

Comment: [Please don't link to cplusplus.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/88241/33100); cppreference.com is much better.

Comment: Above link 404. Maybe https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator